# How to add strings to an array?

Tags: c

How can i add strings to an array like this ? I have a string called "line" which reads users's input and then stores it in "var" . Var is sized [10][40] so it can store 10 strings with the size of 40 each of them (hope that this is what it does ? ) .

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int i=0,n=0;
    char line[40];
    char var[10][40];

    while(n<10){
        gets(line);
        strcpy(var[i],line);
        printf("%s",var[i]);
        i++;
        n++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`gets()` is dangerous and should not be used. Use `fgets()` to read your input and store it in your array.

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline character.It is also better to check the return value of `fgets()` before copying the data from line to your array.

```
   while(i<10){
    fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
    strcpy(var[i],line);
    printf("%s",var[i]);
    i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `fgets`, `gets` is deprecated and dangerous.

The same is also true of `strcpy`, use `strncpy` instead, it allows you to specify the number of characters to copy so that you don't copy through junk memory if your string isn't NULL-terminated.

Then you can remove `n`, you don't need it.  So you pretty much get the same code as Gopi, but DON'T USE  `strcpy` !!!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a line-buffer, write your input directly to var

```
while( n<10 && fgets(var[n],40,stdin)!=0 ){
    strtok(var[n],"\n"); /* remove trailing newline */
    printf("%s",var[n]);
    n++;
}
```